PLAYERINTERACT event called TWICE
Problem with double use of an item during PlayerInteractEvent in a Minecraft plugin
Context: I am developing a plugin for Minecraft version 1.16.5, where a special item FlashDust is added, which when used causes effects on players in a radius. In the code, I register the PlayerInteractEvent event and try to limit the use of the item to filtering by hand by checking event.getHand().
Problem: When the player uses the item, the PlayerInteractEvent event fires twice in a row, causing the item to be used twice even though I filter the events by hand. I have tried using the EquipmentSlot.HAND slot check, but that doesn't solve the problem.
I suspect that the event is being triggered for both the primary and secondary hand, but checking by hand doesn't help.
Here is the code:
package so.max1soft.customitems.dusts;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.NamespacedKey;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.EquipmentSlot;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemFlag;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;
import org.bukkit.Particle;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FlashDust implements Listener {

    private final JavaPlugin plugin;
    private final Map<Player, Long> lastUse = new HashMap<>();

    public FlashDust(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    public static void register(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new FlashDust(plugin), plugin);
    }

    public static ItemStack createItem(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        FileConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig();
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.SUGAR);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();

        if (meta == null) {
            return item;
        }

        String name = config.getString("dusts.flash.name");
        List<String> lore = config.getStringList("dusts.flash.lore");
        meta.setDisplayName(name);
        meta.setLore(lore);

        List<String> enchantments = config.getStringList("dusts.flash.enchantments");

        for (String enchantString : enchantments) {
            String[] parts = enchantString.split(":");
            if (parts.length != 2) {
                plugin.getLogger().warning("Invalid enchantment format: " + enchantString);
                continue;
            }

            String enchantmentName = parts[0].toUpperCase();
            Enchantment enchantment = Enchantment.getByKey(NamespacedKey.minecraft(enchantmentName.toLowerCase()));

            if (enchantment == null) {
                plugin.getLogger().warning("Unknown enchantment: " + enchantmentName);
                continue;
            }

            try {
                int level = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                meta.addEnchant(enchantment, level, true);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                plugin.getLogger().warning("Invalid enchantment level: " + parts[1] + " for enchantment " + enchantmentName);
            }
        }

        meta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ENCHANTS);

        item.setItemMeta(meta);
        return item;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerUseFlasDust(PlayerInteractEvent event) {


            if (event.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND) {
            if (event.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR && event.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                return;
            }


            Player player = event.getPlayer();
            ItemStack item = event.getItem();


            if (item == null || item.getType() != Material.SUGAR) {
                return;
            }

            ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
            if (meta == null || !meta.hasDisplayName() || !meta.getDisplayName().equals(plugin.getConfig().getString("dusts.flash.name"))) {
                return;
            }


            if (lastUse.containsKey(player) && lastUse.get(player) + 1000L > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                return;
            }


            if (!isCooldownActive(player)) {
                player.sendMessage("You are on cooldown!");
                return;
            }


            setCooldown(player);


            event.setCancelled(true);


            processFlasDustUsage(player, item);
        }


    }




    private boolean isCooldownActive(Player player) {
        Long lastInteract = lastUse.get(player);
        if (lastInteract == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastInteract >= 20000L;
    }


    private void setCooldown(Player player) {
        lastUse.put(player, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }


    private void processFlasDustUsage(Player player, ItemStack item) {

        FileConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig();
        String itemName = config.getString("dusts.flash.name");
        List<String> expectedLore = config.getStringList("dusts.flash.lore");

        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        if (!meta.getDisplayName().equals(itemName) || !meta.hasLore() || !meta.getLore().equals(expectedLore)) {
            plugin.getLogger().info("Item does not match expected name or lore, cancelling event.");
            return;
        }


        if (item.getAmount() > 1) {
            item.setAmount(item.getAmount() - 1);
        } else {
            player.getInventory().remove(item);
        }


        applyEffectsAndParticles(player);
    }

    private void applyEffectsAndParticles(Player player) {
        Vector initialLocation = player.getLocation().toVector();
        double fixedY = player.getLocation().getY();

        new BukkitRunnable() {
            double radius = 0;
            final double maxRadius = 7;
            final double step = 0.5;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                radius += step;

                if (radius > maxRadius) {
                    cancel();
                    return;
                }

                for (double angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 10) {
                    double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
                    double x = radius * Math.cos(radians);
                    double z = radius * Math.sin(radians);

                    Vector particleLocation = initialLocation.clone().add(new Vector(x, 0, z));
                    player.getWorld().spawnParticle(Particle.CLOUD, particleLocation.getX(), fixedY + 0.5, particleLocation.getZ(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                }

                for (Player nearbyPlayer : player.getWorld().getPlayers()) {
                    if (nearbyPlayer.equals(player)) continue;
                    if (nearbyPlayer.getLocation().distance(initialLocation.toLocation(player.getWorld())) <= radius) {
                        if (!nearbyPlayer.hasPotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS)) {
                            nearbyPlayer.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS, 7 * 20, 0, false, false));
                            nearbyPlayer.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.POISON, 3 * 20, 0, false, false));
                            nearbyPlayer.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW, 7 * 20, 0, false, false));
                            nearbyPlayer.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.GLOWING, 7 * 20, 0, false, false));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.runTaskTimer(plugin, 0, 2);
    }
}

Main.java Class
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        saveDefaultConfig();
        FileConfiguration config = getConfig();

        // Отладочная информация
        getLogger().info("Спавн Брейкер шанс: " + config.getDouble("spawnbreak.chance"));
        FlashDust.register(this);
        ZenithDust.register(this);
        RadiusPickaxe.register(this);
        AutoSmeltingPickaxe.register(this);
        MagnetPickaxe.register(this);
        CombinedPickaxe.register(this);
        AutoSmeltingShovel.register(this);
        SpawnerBreaker.register(this);
        getCommand("socustomitems").setExecutor(this);
        getCommand("socustomitems").setTabCompleter(new CustomTabCompleter());
    }




    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("socustomitems") && args.length == 3 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("give")) {
            if  (sender.hasPermission("socustomitems.give")) {
                Player target = getServer().getPlayer(args[1]);
                if (target != null) {
                    String pickaxeType = args[2];
                    if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("radius")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(RadiusPickaxe.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("flame")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(AutoSmeltingPickaxe.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("magnet")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(MagnetPickaxe.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("combo")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(CombinedPickaxe.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("flameshovel")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(AutoSmeltingShovel.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("spawnbreaker")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(SpawnerBreaker.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("flashdust")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(FlashDust.createItem(this));
                    } else if (pickaxeType.equalsIgnoreCase("zenithdust")) {
                        target.getInventory().addItem(ZenithDust.createItem(this));
                    } else {
                        sender.sendMessage("Типы: radius, flame, magnet, combo, flameshovel, spawnbreaker, flashdust, zenithdust");
                    }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    sender.sendMessage("Такого кубхеда не существует!");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Welcome on StackOverflow. SO is an english-only website. Can you [edit] your question to translate it in english? Also, can you show your class which is extends JavaPlugin?

update to english :3

Thanks :) Just, can you add your main class in your post too?

Sure i am update it

You have nested another condition inside your hand check, meaning it will only return if both conditions are true. Your condition to check the hand can be refactored into:
if (event.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND && (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
    return
}

This means that the hand must be HAND and the action must be RIGHT_CLICK_AIR or RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK in order to return. You can either split these conditions up or modify it such that they work as you intend.
Split the logic up:
if (event.getHand() != EquipmentSlot.HAND) {
    // Return if the hand isn't HAND (e.g. OFF_HAND)
    return;
}
// Continue the rest of our logic
if (event.getAction()...

Or join the logic correctly:
if (event.getHand() != EquipmentSlot.HAND || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
    return
}

